# Mongoose plugin to assign extra data to a field but not saving to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to write a plugin that should return extra data by setting on a field `tags` already saved to model instead of saving set data on `tags` to database and return.
Here is plugin code.

```
module.exports = function samTagsPlugin(schema, options) {
    schema.post('init', function () {
        document.set('tags', ['a', 'b', 'c']);
    });
};
```

But, the `tags` field is saved to mongodb with the values `['a', 'b', 'c']`. Is there any way I can just assign dynamic value to `tags` and mongoose do not save the provided value to database?
Mongoose version I am using is `3.8.x`.

Comment: Did you tried using [virtual fields?] (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html)

Comment: Just added a virtual field. But how can I set the tags then? `document.set('virtualTags', ['a', 'b', 'c']);` is not working. Getting `virtualTags: undefined`

Comment: Just figured it out. Now working.
Thanks @Manu

Comment: have you considered adding to your plugin `schema.pre('save', function (next) {
        console.log("not persisting tags");
        console.log(document);
        document.set('tags', null);
        next()
    })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I solved this using `virtual` fields (Thanks @Manu).

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    uiGrid: {name: 'Type', order: 15},
    required: true
  },
  contactNumber: {type: String, uiForm: {name: 'Contact Number'}},
  __customTags: [String]
}, {
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true
  },
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true
  }
});
```

Not that here I have added a field **`__customTags`**. In mongoose everything starts with **`__`** will not be persisted to database.
And then

```
MySchema.virtual('tags').get(function() {
  return this.__customTags;
}).set(function(tags) {
  this.__customTags = tags;
});
```

From my plugin, I am assigning `tags` to an array of values I want.

```
this.set('tags', tags);
```